# How to make my absolute cover the whole container with overflow scroll?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have a container (`position: relative`) with limited height (in my HTML it's limited by a flex box so I actually don't have the `200px` as in the below code shows). It has the content that determines its width and height. Above the content, I have an `absolute` cover with a background to partially cover the content.

However, when the content overflows, and scrollbars appear, the `.cover` element does not stretch out. I have tried the following:

- `width` and `height` to `100%`.
- `right` and `bottom` to `0`.
- From another SO answer I cannot find again, I set `min-height: 100%` and `bottom: auto`.

None of the above stretch the `.cover` to match the content. Is it possible?

```css
p {
  width: 2000px; /* Simulating a wide content */
  height: 300px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0;
}

.my-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;  
  height: 200px; /* Simulating limited space */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.my-container .cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  /* I have tried each of these: */
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  min-height: 100%;
  bottom: auto;      
}

.my-container .cover span {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div>
    <p>Very long text line or very wide image.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cover">
    <span class="cover-content">Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .cover (absolute) container (relative) is 200px, height 100% , or bottom 0 right 0 on it give the size of it's relative parent the container. Not the size of the p

Comment: @pierfarrugia yeah I understand that part, just don't know a solution.

Comment: @pierfarrugia but thanks to your comment, I realized I could separate the current container into a wrapper and have its role separated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "pier farrugia"'s comment, I realized I could make a scrolling container separate from the cover parent. So I just need to add another wrapper:

```css
.scrolling-container {
  overflow: auto;  
  height: 200px; /* Simulating limited space */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  width: 2000px; /* Simulating a wide content */
  height: 300px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0;
}

.my-container {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content; /* This is needed to expand the width to match content */
}

.my-container .cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);     
}

.my-container .cover span {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-container">
  <div class="my-container">
    <div>
      <p>Very long text line or very wide image.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cover">
      <span class="cover-content">Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

Set the display to `inline-block` of all the parents of that `p` tag so that they can get stretched following the child width. It can't  be done with 100% width.

```
.my-container{display: inline-block;}
.my-container div:first-child{display: inline-block;}
```

```css
   p {
      width: 2000px; /* Simulating a wide content */
      height: 300px;
      background: cornflowerblue;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .my-container {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;  
      height: 200px; /* Simulating limited space */
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .my-container .cover {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
      /* I have tried each of these: */
      /*height: 100%;*/
      /*bottom: 0;*/
      min-height: 100%;
      bottom: auto;      
    }

    .my-container .cover span {
      background: white;
      padding: 1rem;
      margin: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <p>Very long text line or very wide image.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cover">
    <span class="cover-content">Hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the space below though (you can see when scrolling down). See my answer and the other comment. The `display: inline-block` behavior can simply be achieved using `width: fit-content`.